# How can I reuse dynamic html in twig (twig function?)

Tags: twig

I'm using Twig and not an expert at it yet.
I have the following code I'm using in many places and would like to pass in one variable (active) which could be null to a twig function or template for reuse. I've looked and functions in twig don't seem possible. Using a template and passing a variable seems plausible?

Here is the html with an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<span class="float-end text-nowrap">
 <a href="?"><i class="{{ if active==1 ? "text-success" }} bi bi-check2-circle"></i></a>
 <a href="?"><i class="{{ if active==2 ? "text-warning" }} bi bi-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
 <a href="?"><i class="{{ if active==3 ? "text-danger" }} bi bi-sign-stop-fill"></i></a>
</span>
```

Comment: Did you look into [marco's](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't familiar with macros in twig and Darkbees recommendation was correct.
Example

```
{% macro rate( active = 0, url ) %}
        <span class="float-end text-nowrap">
        {% if active == 1 %}
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(1, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-success bi bi-check-circle-fill"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(2, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-muted bi bi-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(3, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-muted bi bi-sign-stop"></i></a>
        {% elseif active == 2%}
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(1, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-muted bi bi-check-circle"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(2, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-warning bi bi-exclamation-triangle-fill"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(3, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-muted bi bi-sign-stop"></i></a>
        {% elseif active == 3%}
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(1, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-muted bi bi-check-circle"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(2, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-muted bi bi-exclamation-triangle"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:ajax_rateit(3, '{{ url }}')"><i class="text-danger bi bi-sign-stop-fill"></i></a>
        {% endif %}
        </span>
{% endmacro %}
```